# asp.net - infinite loop foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, file-upload, foreach

```
foreach (HttpPostedFile file in filePhotos.PostedFiles)
{
    RandomStringGenerator rnd = new RandomStringGenerator();
    string filename = rnd.Generate(5) + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
    file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Photos/") + filename);
    Sweet_Shailene___EN.Photo p = new Sweet_Shailene___EN.Photo();
    p.GalleryId = Convert.ToInt32(drpGallery.SelectedValue);
    p.Url = filename;
    db.Photos.Add(p);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

and it's gone to an infinite loop! anybody can help?

Comment: Are you saving and reading files from the same folder?

Comment: this is the part where you set breakpoints in your code and step through it.. have you done that at least..?

Comment: Yes, as MethodMan described you need to use the debugger first. And then there is one important performance flaw in your code. You are using db.SaveChanges() inside the for loop which will impact the performance of the application. Please check.

Comment: @Varun Thanks! i put db.saveChanges() outside of foreach and problem solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally Thanks to Varun i put the

```
db.saveChanges();
```

outside of foreach